# PHP MySQL - Left Join 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, left-join

i have a logic problem in my PHP/SQL Code.

My script delivers a list of titles. You can view a single title by clicking on it (ajax). In this process, the list is saving in the database.

If you click "back" you should see the previous list again.
And here is my problem...

Table ca_begriff

```
id  title
2   Giraffe
3   Wetterhahn
4   Eiswürfel
5   Toaster
```

Table ca_history

```
id  date
46  1452592732
45  1452592731
44  1452592662
```

Table ca_history_begriffe

```
id      history begriff position
263     46      3       1
264     46      9       2
265     46      10      3
266     46      2       4
267     46      4       5
```

The Problem must be here:

```
$sql = "SELECT begriffe.id, begriffe.title FROM ca_begriffe
        LEFT JOIN ca_history_begriffe ON ca_begriffe.id = ca_history_begriffe.begriff
        LEFT JOIN ca_history ON ca_history_begriffe.history = ca_history.id
        WHERE ca_history.id = ".$_GET['r']."
        ORDER BY ca_history_begriffe.position";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Thank you

Greets from Germany

Comment: And the question is????

Comment: How do you form or define 'history id' (passes as $_GET['r']) before certain title is clicked?

Comment: $_GET['r'] is the id that is generated before with a INSERT command.

Comment: $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ca_history (datum) VALUES (".time().")");
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

Comment: may be incorrect column names begriffe.id, begriffe.title

Comment: nope. many times checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you specified a wrong column names

```
$sql = "SELECT ca_begriffe.id, ca_begriffe.title FROM ca_begriffe
    LEFT JOIN ca_history_begriffe ON ca_begriffe.id = ca_history_begriffe.begriff
    LEFT JOIN ca_history ON ca_history_begriffe.history = ca_history.id
    WHERE ca_history.id = ".$_GET['r']."
    ORDER BY ca_history_begriffe.position";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the error is: "non-object", but you didn't post that code. A right use below:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   // $row is filled!
}
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Ajax is not the Problem. I deliver by GET the ca_history.id. this works fine. just my SQL with the left joins are the problem

Comment: But what's the problem? Error? No result?

Comment: The problem is the sql query. the id will be delivered. that works fine. but i cant get the titles from ca_begriffe by searching for history id...

Comment: Ok, the title field in de query result is null?

Comment: $_GET["r"] -> ca_history.id -> ca_history_begriffe.history -> ca_history_begriffe.begriff -> ca_begriffe.id -> ca_begriffe.title thats my logic. the result now is just an error. "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object..."

Comment: Check my changed answer

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
ca_begriffe.id, ca_begriffe.title
```

sorry. that was stupid. I forgot that "ca_". It has been years ago since my last SQL project. Thank you guys!